could bonding mode 6 receive traffic load balancing to the slaves
Is the mode 6 traffic will receive load balance relatively according to the slaves interfaces?
OS: ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS; bonding driver: v3.7.1; kernel: 4.15.0-213-generic
In mode 6, I had setted the parameter bond_arp_interval 100, arp_validate 3 and bond_arp_ip_target ip1,ip2 and restart interface, then only get ip1 from file /sys/class/net/bond6/bonding/arp_ip_target, but get 0 from both file /sys/class/net/bond6/bonding/arp_interval and /sys/class/net/bond6/bonding/arp_validate, and pushed the traffic to the dest host by iperf3, all traffic from different src hosts with different arp records(same dest ip with different mac addresses which belong to the dest host mode 6 bonding slaves) always received by the same slave interface in dest host. Maybe the ARP record does not update properly in the subnet, so it can't receive traffic load balancing.
And I tested bond_arp_interval 100, arp_validate 3 and bond_arp_ip_target ip1 in mode 1, it works, reference to this redhat solution. Maybe arp probes not suitable for mode 6? Why mode 6 say it could achieve that receive traffic balancing?
How the bonding driver initiates an ARP reply to the peer for updating the ARP record? I can't find any other parameter to work for it.
Linux Ethernet Bonding Driver HOWTO :

Receive load balancing is handled by Address Resolution Protocol (ARP) negotiation and table mapping to the relevant group interface.


Hence, peers learn the hardware address
of the bond and the balancing of receive traffic
collapses to the current slave.  This is handled by
sending updates (ARP Replies) to all the peers with
their individually assigned hardware address such that
the traffic is redistributed.

Questions:
1, how bonding achieve that the mode 6 receive traffic load balancing to the slaves?
2, why it doesn't work with arp monitor in mode 6?
3, could it work in Distributed VXLAN Gateway with dynamically learns ARP entries and ARP broadcast suppression?
4, when two Distributed VXLAN Gateway(Q3) leaves learned the same host IP ARP entry but with different mac addresses from local network(switch port), what would they do?
I can't find any answer in unix.stackexchange.com, so I come here ask this question.
